# Как вызвать программу и считать её вывод?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Необходимо запустить внешнюю программу и прочитать её стандартный вывод. Внешняя программа запускается, выводит результат и сразу завершается, например ls. Платформа linux, язык программирования c++, нужно использовать только стандартную библиотеку и системные вызовы.

Пока есть только такой вариант

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::system("ls >lsout.txt");
    std::cout << std::ifstream("lsout.txt").rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: [`popen()`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=popen&category=3)?

Comment: ¿А что не так с этим вариантом?

Comment: @user7860670 лишний файл неопределенного размера. может сожрать весь диск или всю память

Answer (score 1):

Возможно использовать функцию [popen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

```
    fflush(stdout);
    FILE* fd = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (fd != nullptr) {
        char buf[10];
        for (int r = 0; (r = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fd)) > 0;) {
            out_data.append(static_cast<const char*>(buf), r);
        }

        pclose(fd);
    }
```